# Case nested in a loop, PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: case

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to build a horizontal table and have assigned the query through the explicit cursor QUERY_H, additionally, I built a static list with dual and assigned it to the explicit cursor QUERY_Q. But I keep hitting the error listed in the title:

```
ORA-06550: line 113, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the 
following:

   case
The symbol "case" was substituted for ";" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Below is the portion of script being used:

```
FOR QUERY_R IN QUERY_H
    LOOP
    case when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'QUERY_Date' then
        FOR record IN QUERY_Q
            LOOP
                  htp.p('<td bgcolor="E6E6D2" align="center" width="40px" height="40px" class="normal12px"><b>&nbsp;'||record.QUERY_Date||'&nbsp;</b></td>');
            END LOOP;
    when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'col3' then htp.p('');
    when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'col4' then
        htp.p('</tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center"><b>'||QUERY_R.HTML_TEXT||'</b></td>');
        FOR record IN QUERY_Q
            LOOP
                  htp.p(record.col4);
            END LOOP;
    when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'col5' then
        htp.p('</tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center"><b>'||QUERY_R.HTML_TEXT||'</b></td>');
        FOR record IN QUERY_Q
            LOOP
                  htp.p(record.col5);
            END LOOP;
    else htp.p('
        <td height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center"><b>'||QUERY_R.HTML_TEXT||'</b></td>');
        FOR record IN QUERY_Q
            LOOP
                htp.p('<td width="40px" height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center">'||record.col6||'</td>');
            END LOOP;
    END;
END LOOP;
```

what needs to change to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry can't test it right now, but you shouldn't get this error if you use "END CASE;" in line 31, as follows :

```
FOR QUERY_R IN QUERY_H
LOOP
case when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'QUERY_Date' then
    FOR record IN QUERY_Q
        LOOP
              htp.p('<td bgcolor="E6E6D2" align="center" width="40px" height="40px" class="normal12px"><b>&nbsp;'||record.QUERY_Date||'&nbsp;</b></td>');
        END LOOP;
when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'col3' then htp.p('');
when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'col4' then
    htp.p('</tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center"><b>'||QUERY_R.HTML_TEXT||'</b></td>');
    FOR record IN QUERY_Q
        LOOP
              htp.p(record.col4);
        END LOOP;
when QUERY_R.QUERY_HEADER like 'col5' then
    htp.p('</tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center"><b>'||QUERY_R.HTML_TEXT||'</b></td>');
    FOR record IN QUERY_Q
        LOOP
              htp.p(record.col5);
        END LOOP;
else htp.p('
    <td height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center"><b>'||QUERY_R.HTML_TEXT||'</b></td>');
    FOR record IN QUERY_Q
        LOOP
            htp.p('<td width="40px" height="40px" bgcolor="E6E6D2" class="normal12px" align="center">'||record.col6||'</td>');
        END LOOP;
END CASE;
END LOOP;
```

Try this! Cya!

--

Edited to explain: You are using the case *expression*, not the *statement*. Case statements should aways end with **END CASE**.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems004.htm

Comment: First, Welcome to SO! Second, Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Because a `case ..when` expression which's not included within a select statement  should be ended by `end case;` which should be replaced with `end;` just before `end loop;` at the bottom of your code.